# fs.unlink EBUSY error

Tags: node.js

I am trying to delete a file in nodejs. When I run the following code:

```
try {
   fs.unlinkSync('file');
} catch(e) {
   console.log(e)
}
```

I get the following error.

```
Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, unlink '<redacted>'
    at Object.fs.unlinkSync (fs.js:1067:18)
    at Function.rimrafSync [as sync] (<redacted>\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:306:17)
    at <redacted>:74:10
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function.module.exports.sync (<redacted>\node_modules\node-delete\index.js:67:30)
    at <filepath>:4145:46
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at <redacted>:4142:21
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
  errno: -4082,
  code: 'EBUSY',
  syscall: 'unlink',
  path: '<redacted>'
```

Comment: The file is being used by any other program.

I think the message is clear.

Answer (score 2):

This error means the file you're trying to delete is currently in use or locked.

Answer (score 0):

Without providing more informations we will guess, that the file you are trying to delete is locked by another program. Please check this...